# DateTime and LinqToEntities

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have DateTime field, which storing date + time. I need to use only date part, so I try:

```
            query = query.Where(p => p.CreatedDateTime.Date == DateStart);
```

but I get the following error:

> The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
>   Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties
>   are supported.

why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what about this:

```
query = query.Where(p => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(p.CreatedDateTime) == DateStart);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use extension functions in `LINQ` queries that result in a database hit if `Entity Framework` has no way to convert this into valid `SQL`.

There may be a more compact solution but the following should work fine:

```
query = query.Where(p => 
    p.CreatedDateTime.Year == DateStart.Year &&
    p.CreatedDateTime.Month == DateStart.Month &&
    p.CreatedDateTime.Day == DateStart.Day);
```